# bundler.require doesn't work for me

Tags: ruby, bundler

According to the Bundler site, using `Bundler.require` eliminates the need to explicitly require Gems at the top of your classes. Specifically, the site says,

*"If you have a lot of dependencies, you might want to say "require all of the gems in my Gemfile".* To do this, put the following code immediately following require 'bundler/setup':

```
Bundler.require(:default)"
```

When I do this and remove dependencies at the top of my class file, things break. For example, removing the following statement from an application class:

```
"require hpricot"
```

will cause the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `Hpricot' for #<IndexBuilder:0x000000016365e0>
```

even though my Rakefile says,

```
"Bundler.require(:default, environment.to_s)"
```

and i have Hpricot listed in my Gemfile.

Any thoughts on what i'm doing wrong here? I am calling `'require bundler/setup'` at the top of my Rakefile as they say I should.

---EDIT---

**Thanks for your responses. My Gemfile follows; I've removed whitespace here just to save on space:**

source "https://rubygems.org"

ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rake'

gem 'require_all'

gem 'ruby-progressbar'

gem 'hpricot'

**And the file that is doing the 'require' -**

require 'open-uri'

## require 'hpricot'

class IndexBuilder

# presumes source is an web URL containing a list of web-linked songs.
  def build(source)
    data = Array.new
    fetch(source).search("//a").each do |a|
      song = Song.new(a.inner_html, a.to_s)
      data << song
    end
    Index.new(data)
  end

def fetch(source)
    open(source) {|f| Hpricot(f) }
  end

private :fetch

end

Comment: Could you post your Gemfile and class that is doing the `Bundle.require`?

Comment: Please show a part of your code that uses bundler require and then `Hprikot`... add please, load `irb` with `bundle exec irb`, and then issue the line: `Bundler.require(:default); Hpricot`